# JQuery: change image on click

Tags: jquery, image, replace

Hoping someone here can help as I've spent hours googling this to no avail :/

Basically what I need is this function that someone already created: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/2/)

```
$(function(){

  $("#big-image img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();
  $(".small-images img").click(function(e){
    var index = $(this).index();
    $("#big-image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
   });
});
```

But when a thumbnail is clicked it needs to change to a different image as well, to indicate which image is active. (the small images will be arrows in my example)

I've managed to get it to change by using replace() with _on.png and _off.png, but I can't get them to change back to the original png when a new one is clicked.

Comment: I don't quite understand? It needs to change to a different image? What needs to change? And please - for the love of all that is holy, format your code.

Comment: Maybe change the src-attribute? http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

You could just add/remove class:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/270/)

```
$(function(){
    $("#big-image img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();
    $(".small-images img:eq(0)").addClass('selected');
    $(".small-images img").click(function(e){
        var index = $(this).index();
        $("#big-image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add two extra lines of jQuery code to add/remove class on the thumbnail that was clicked:

```
$(function () {
    $("#big-image img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();
    $(".small-images span").click(function (e) {
        $("#big-image img").eq($(this).index()).show().siblings().hide();
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    }).eq(0).addClass("active");
});
```

... throw in some CSS:

```css
.small-images span {
    /* following three lines set the icon dimensions */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    /* following two lines hide the text inside icon */
    text-indent: -1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* following two lines display an icon from the "sprite" */
    background-image: url(sprite.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
    /* etc etc */
    cursor: pointer;
}
.small-images span:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
.small-images span.active {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

[**Result**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Qhdaz/272/)

Comment: But that just adds a border - what I need is for the image to change.

Comment: Sorry, hitting "enter" posted the comment :) Pretend those small thumbnails are blue arrows. When I click an arrow it needs to change to pink. Then when I click a different arrow, the pink one needs to return to blue. Is this making sense?

Comment: Do you want pager (prev - next) buttons instead of thumbnails? Note: you can still use CSS to display an arrow over thumbnails, any color.

Comment: I have revised my answer. I did not change much except for CSS. You need to add an arrow image to each "thumbnail" as CSS background image. The `.active` class can have different background color (or image).

Comment: That's great, looks like it might do the trick! I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this

```
$(function(){
    $("#big-image img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();
    $(".small-images img").click(function(e){
        var index = $(this).index();
        $(this).css('border','2px solid red').siblings().removeAttr('style');
        $("#big-image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/268/)